# Why is the lock on synchronized block not working?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I wrote a **SharedObject** class which has two methods to increment a variable. The expected result is **200000** but it shows much less than that. I thought the synchronized block will acquire lock on the **cnt** variable and thus no two threads can modify or access it but it's not happening. Why is it so?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SharedObject sharedObject = new SharedObject();
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sharedObject.produce();
            }
        });
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sharedObject.consume();
            }
        });
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
        producer.join();
        consumer.join();
        System.out.println(sharedObject.cnt);
    }
    static class SharedObject {
        Integer cnt = 0;
        void produce() {
            for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
                synchronized (cnt) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
        void consume() {
            for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
                synchronized (cnt) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try defining `cnt` as `final`, and you should see the problem.

Comment: As an aside: for this concrete problem, I recommend using [`AtomicInteger` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of `Integer`. This will eliminate the need to use `synchronized`.

Comment: how can i modify the **cnt** variable if it is declared as final? @Turing85

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding. You cannot modify `Integer`-instances; they are immutable.

Comment: Locks are acquired on objects, not variables. When the value of `cnt` changes, that causes different threads to acquire different locks.

Comment: I replace **Integer cnt = 0** with **MyInt cnt = new MyInt();** adding
static class MyInt {int val = 0;} and then it works

Comment: Understood. Tnx @Turing85